# Properties of bounded minimum and average degree graph

Tags: graphs

Let us have a weighted graph $G$. We are interested in a subgraph, $H$ of $G$ where each vertex has a degree at least a natural number $b(v)$. I am interested in a subgraph where the sum of the edges of the subgraph is minimized. This problem is known as $b$-edge cover. The optimization formulation is as follows.

\begin{align}
\min\ & w(e)x(e) \\
st & \sum_{e \in \delta(v)} x(e) \geq b(v) \\
& x(e) \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

Here $\delta(v)$ is set of adjacent edges of $v$. Let $\beta_1 = \max_{v} b(v)$, $\beta_2 = \min_{v} b(v)$

It is easy to see that subgraph $H$ has a minimum degree $\beta_2$. I believe the average degree of $H$ is also bounded by $O(\beta_1)$. In this model, I want to know the properties of the subgraph $H$, e.g., the connectivity, degree distribution, clustering properties, e.t.c. Are there any references that discuss this class of graphs?

Comment: "How likely the graph is connected? How is the degree distribution?" - to talk about this, you need to specify a distribution from which the graph is taken (information you've provided is not enough). There are many random graph models, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph) for some examples. I believe for many of them the answers to your questions are known. If your distribution is "select each graph with these properties with equal probability", you need to specify whether you differentiate between isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Thanks. I am working with random graphs. I edited the question to make it informative.

Comment: But from which distribution does graph $G$ come? How do we decide whether there is an edge between vertices, and what is the weight of the edge? (I also suspect that no matter what the distribution is, the question is too hard).

Comment: If edge weights are positive and $b(v)=2$ for all $v$, all subgraphs $H$ are vertex-disjoint cycle covers; if $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle (which is NP-complete to determine), $H$ might be such a cycle and thus be connected, otherwise it is definitely not connected. This suggests that determining connectivity will be difficult for this problem in general. Also: If edge weights are positive and $b(v)=1$ for all $v$, all subgraphs $H$ are perfect matchings.

Comment: @l_random_hacker. If $b(v)=1$, H may not be a perfect matching. Think when $G$ is a star. One can also find examples where $b(v)=2$ may not lead to vertex-disjoint cycles.

Comment: Well, *if a solution exists* then it is a perfect matching or a set of vertex-disjoint cycles, respectively.

Comment: You may be interested in this somewhat related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378933/random-subgraph-properties/379863#379863